# How to limit foreach loop to 3 results as icons in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this piece of code that is showing all results as icons, but it shows nearly 50 icons in each loop. I searched many ways to change it to 3 icons in each loop unsuccessfully. How can I do that?

```
foreach ($categoryItems as $item) { 

    if ($item['categoryId'] != $category['id'])
        continue;

    $itemXML = $items->findItemInXML($item['itemId']);
    $subContent .= "<a class=\"thumbnail\" ><img src=\"images/gameIcons/".$items->getIcon($itemXML).".png\" alt=\"Item icon\" align=\"top\" />";
}

$subContent .= "</td>
<td class=\"tablePreview ui-state-hover\">
<a href=\"showMore\">More information</a>
</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: Why not using a `for` loop then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the `continue` condition, my suggestion to use a `for` loop is less relevant. Instead you can use a `counter variable` to count how many icons have been printed. Once that counter reach 3 it breaks the loop. 
(Didn't tested it)

```
$printedIcons = 0;
foreach ($categoryItems as $item) { 

    if($printedIcons == 3)
        break;
    if ($item['categoryId'] != $category['id'])
        continue;

    $itemXML = $items->findItemInXML($item['itemId']);
    $subContent .= "<a class=\"thumbnail\" ><img src=\"images/gameIcons/".$items->getIcon($itemXML).".png\" alt=\"Item icon\" align=\"top\" />";
    $printedIcons++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a count variable and while loop to iterate until 3rd icon is executed.

```
foreach ($categoryItems as $item) { 

  $count=0;
  while(count<=2) {
    if ($item['categoryId'] != $category['id'])
    continue;

  $itemXML = $items->findItemInXML($item['itemId']);
  $subContent .= "<a class=\"thumbnail\" ><img src=\"images/gameIcons/".$items->getIcon($itemXML).".png\" alt=\"Item icon\" align=\"top\" />";
    }
  count++;  
  }
}
```